# MapBox setting multiple markers through props react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I have a map box react component which take in a cats object via props with lng and lat cordinates.

```
<MapContainer cats={cats} /> ----- This is component below


componentDidMount() {

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: this.mapContainer,
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
  zoom: this.state.zoom
});

map.on('move', () => {
  this.setState({
    lng: map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4),
    lat: map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4),
    zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
  });
});

//var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
//.setLngLat([12.550343, 55.665957])
//.addTo(map);

this.props.cats.map((cat) => {
console.log('test');
  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
  .setLngLat([cat.lat, cat.lng])
  .addTo(this.map);
});

}
```

The commented out section of the code adds a map marker fine from following the tutorial.

However, in the code below I am trying to map through my cat props object to add multiple markers, but the console.log('test'); doesn't appear in the console so I must be doing something wrong.

Its been a while since I have done some React, please point me in the right direction?! :)

Fixed:

this.props.cats was empty inside componentDidMount() so I moved the code inside
componentWillReceiveProps() which fixed it! :)

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(this.props.cats)`  in `componentDidMount()`? One probable reason map doesn't log could be that cats props is empty array.

Comment: Yes I did inside the render function and that does console log 6 cats (lol) to the console

Comment: cats: this.props.cats <<< If I put the props.cats into state, then console.log('Test', this.state.cats); does not return any cats in the render function? hmmm

Comment: But does it give you 6 cats inside `componentDidMount` function? Or even 1 cat?

Comment: Ahh know it does not! Its an empty array inside there.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps() moving the code inside here fixed it!

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is deprecated and unsafe, see [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) you can move your logic inside `componentDidUpdate`, sideEffects should be handled inside `componentDidUpdate` and non-side effects can be handled inside `render`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your cats are not available when component mounts but available later on, that is why they appear in render but an empty array is available during `componentDidMount`.

You need to add your marker after your cats are available. You can move your logic to add in `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook and add a check like the following.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Handle your condition here, something like below
  // Make sure to add a condition to run only when required, because componentDidUpdate will run each time prop or state has changed.
  if(this.props.cat.length > 0 && this.props.cat !== prevProps.cat ) {
    // Your marker logic
      }
}
```